# The information I am trying to get says undefined. Any suggestions?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get the following information from an API response. However, whenever I pull the information to only grab the listed info from the data, they are all listed as `undefined`.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AnyArray } from 'mongoose';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchCountryData (country: string) {
    let formattedCountry = country.split('-').join(' ');
    let api1 = `http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/${formattedCountry}?format=json`;
    let api2 = ``
    return this.http.get(api1)
  }

  setCountryData(country: string) {
    let subject = new Subject();

    this.fetchCountryData(country).subscribe((data: any) => {
       subject.next({
        country: data.name,
        capital: data.capitalCity,
        income: data.incomeLevel,
        region: data.adminregion,
        latitude: data.latitude,
        longitude: data.longitude,
       }) 
    })

    return subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The API response is as follows:

```
(2) [{…}, Array(1)]
0
: 
{page: 1, pages: 1, per_page: '50', total: 1}
1
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
adminregion
: 
{id: 'EAP', iso2code: '4E', value: 'East Asia & Pacific (excluding high income)'}
capitalCity
: 
"Beijing"
id
: 
"CHN"
incomeLevel
: 
{id: 'UMC', iso2code: 'XT', value: 'Upper middle income'}
iso2Code
: 
"CN"
latitude
: 
"40.0495"
lendingType
: 
{id: 'IBD', iso2code: 'XF', value: 'IBRD'}
longitude
: 
"116.286"
name
: 
"China"
region
: 
{id: 'EAS', iso2code: 'Z4', value: 'East Asia & Pacific'}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I have tried everything I can think of, but I am getting errors for trying to specify the array the data is in since it's labelled as an integer. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. What I was doing was `data.name` or `data[1].name` or `data[0].name`. What worked was `data[1][0].name`.

This is probably because it's nesting inside of 2 separate arrays.